# error when runing .cpp file in terminal using g++

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, g++

I trying `RabbitMQ` + `C++`. Working on linux ubuntu 16.04. Have working code and when I compile using `CLion` all works fine.
I have peace of code what I need to run with root, so I want to run it using `g++`.

**ERROR FROM TERMINAL**

```
In function `main':
receiveUNPW.cpp:(.text+0x8e8): undefined reference to `SimplePocoHandler::SimplePocoHandler(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned short)'
receiveUNPW.cpp:(.text+0xc9c): undefined reference to `SimplePocoHandler::loop()'
receiveUNPW.cpp:(.text+0xcce): undefined reference to `SimplePocoHandler::~SimplePocoHandler()'
receiveUNPW.cpp:(.text+0xea7): undefined reference to `SimplePocoHandler::~SimplePocoHandler()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libamqpcpp.so: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
```

I write :

```
g++ -std=c++11 receiveUNPW.cpp -o receiveUNPW -lcrypt -lPocoNet -lPocoFoundation -lamqpcpp
```

**CMakeList.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

add_library(poco_simple_handler SimplePocoHandler.cpp SimplePocoHandler.h)
target_link_libraries(poco_simple_handler PocoNet PocoFoundation crypt )

set(PROGS
        sendUNPW
        receiveUNPW
        )

foreach(item ${PROGS})
    add_executable(${item} "${item}.cpp")
    target_link_libraries(${item} amqpcpp poco_simple_handler PocoNet PocoFoundation crypt)
endforeach(item)
```

**MY IDEA**

As can see when I use `g++` it can't find reference to `SimplePocoHandler`. In `CmakeList.txt` i have

```
add_library(poco_simple_handler SimplePocoHandler.cpp SimplePocoHandler.h)
target_link_libraries(poco_simple_handler PocoNet PocoFoundation crypt )
```

so when I compile in CLion all works fine. So seems I need to do the same when I using `g++`. But I don't know how to do it, any suggestions or explanations would be great.

I don't share my `receiveUNPW.cpp` code, but it's almost similar to that `receiver.cpp` what you can see [there](https://github.com/RPG-18/rabbitmq-cpp-tutorials/tree/master/src) and also I don't have any error there, in `CLion` all works fine, I just need to run my program using terminal with root permissions.

Comment: "I have peace of code what I need to run with root, so I need to run it using g++" - Why would you need to compile the code as root in order to run it as root?

Comment: @JesperJuhl How do you mean run as root? I don't want to set privileges to project folder and etc.. I just want run code using g++, test it and then maybe make script or something to run it automatically.

Comment: One does not "run" code with g++. g++ is a compiler (probably the same compiler used by CLion). Compilers compile code and generate executables (programs) that you then run (execute). The compiler doesn't run the program.

Comment: @JesperJuhl ook, so if I understand right, I don't need to compile my code using g++ again. I need executable file from CLion what I will run with root permissions?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I don't even know how to make that file.. That's why I want to compile with `g++` and make it (as one of possible solution)..  You know how to do it? I understand that I need executable file to run it with root... But I need to create it before..

Comment: @JesperJuhl ohh, now I get it.. I found where are saved all my executable files in linux, and run code, all works fine. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run your code as root, change to a root shell using `su -` and then execute the binary that CLion generated. Or run it using `sudo`. You can also set the suid bit on the executable and make it be owned by root then it will always run as root, but that's not recommended - too many security issues possible.

You don't need to recompile an application as root to run it as root.

Edit with example as requested:

A simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello world\n";
}
```

Compiling it:

`$ g++ hello.cc`

Running it:

```
$ ./a.out
Hello world
$
```

Running it as root:

```
$ su -
# /path/to/program/a.out
Hello world
#
```